# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop installation using preseed freezing after partitioning

Tags: preseed

I'm trying to automate ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop installation using seed file, but unfortunately I'm unable to proceed futher after patitioning step while installation, as the window got hang.

Even I copy - paste entire "https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt" still the same problem

Below is the current configuration

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i passwd/user-fullname string test host
d-i passwd/username string test
d-i passwd/user-password password ubuntutest
d-i passwd/user-password-again password ubuntutest
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
d-i pkgsel/include string ssh vim build-essential  
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none
```

I just mention the seed files in the boot params as 
auto url=http://192.168.56.101/test.cfg

Here I'm testing on Virtual box.

Please suggest

Comment: how exactly are you proceeding? give us a step by step, if you have a script, show it to us so that we can understand the issue.

Comment: Now i read this article and found that https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation tasksel, netcfg can't add in ubiquity installer.

Comment: @tatsu there is no script, only I'm maintaining preseed file to answer for all installation question, then proceed with script. Also I see there were so many issues with ubiquity-installer , need to figure out this., d-i replaced by which params